# My IK rig won't flip properly

Tags: animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics

i'm having problems with my IK rig. I'm working on a generic character model rig with multiple animations. One of these animations is a walk cycle and a practice that a lot of people implement is the use of "paste flipped" in order to make animating easier.

Although, when using my IK rig, the paste flipped option doesn't work in the way that it should. As you can see, when I try to flip the keyframes, the legs get all buggy and weird. I just want to know how to fix this problem so that I can animate walk and run cycles easier.

[image]

Comment: Is your rig well centered (origin in the world center, torso bones with no X coordinates different than 0)? Do all of your side bones have the correct suffix (.L, .R or .l, .r, or .Left, .right)?

Comment: side bones? Are those the ik bones?

Comment: I called side bones all bones which have a "mirrored" sibling (like arms, legs, shoulders ...)

Comment: oh, yeah im pretty sure. The human rig isn't mines, but they are labeled as Right and Left. Also, this doesn't occur with any other body part; just the legs that are IK'd. If i were to get them back to forward kinematics, it would flip like regular.